# Size cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Size annotation is not found and I get **Size cannot be resolved to a type** .Although **import javax.validation.constraints.Size;** is added I get this error.

> import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
>
> import lombok.Data;
>
> @Data public class UserCreateDTO {        @Size   private String firstName;
> private String lastName;
>
> }

[image: size annotation not found error]

My dependencies in POM.xml are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: you import it, but that red line beneath the import statement kind of implies that the import isn't found.

Comment: Add `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters

Validation Starter no longer included in web starters
As of #19550, Web and WebFlux starters do not depend on the validation starter by default anymore. If your application is using validation features, for example you find that javax.validation.* imports are not being resolved, you’ll need to add the starter yourself.

For Maven builds, you can do that with the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For Gradle, you will need to add something like this:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```